# Illogical size of localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I read that the max size of the localStorage is around <kbd>5MB</kbd>. But I did something very strange that shows another result.

---

I copied a `1024x768` image from internet (for startup image) then converted it to base 64. I put it in a file and saw that the file was <kbd>300KB</kbd>. Then, I wrote the code below :

```
for(var a;a<1000;a++)
{
    try{localStorage["'"+a+"'"]="The very long string of 75000 characteres";}
    catch(e)
    {
        alert("No !");
        break;
    }
}
alert("Yes !");
```

And my iPad alerted `Yes !`. 1000*300=300000KB -> <kbd>300MB</kbd>. It means that the localStorage stored <kbd>300MB</kbd> of information!

How is this possible? Is the localStorage compressing or something?

**EDIT :** Finally, it was a typo. `for(var a;a<1000;a++)` instead of `for(var a=0;a<1000;a++)`. And if someone wants to know, I storred succesfully 6 images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your for loop never executed because you didn't initialize your loop variable.  Try

```
for(var a=0;a<1000;a++)
```

Comment: Carefully compare the first line of code in your question to the line in my answer.  You will see an important difference.

Comment: Yes, thank you. It works. Don't I have to delete this stupid question?

Comment: You don't have to delete it.  The literal question isn't likely to be very helpful to many people in the future.  But having example code for localStorage on iPad sure could be useful.  And don't feel bad -- identifying the source of problem is a big part of building software.